# How do I register a user?

Tags: 7, services

I am using Drupal 7.17 and the Services module 7.3.2.

I set the Services module as in the following screenshots.

[image]

[image]

I followed the documentation on http://drupal.org/node/1447020.

With FireFox HttpRequester, I tried to register a new user.

[image]

I got a 500 error.

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have any required fields in user profile? If yes - you must specify their values in your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently , there is a field of that name ... and some node / entity which is trying to get saved automatically. Could you have Profile2 installed ?
Did you try the report on admin/reports/fields ?
If you dont find it there, try the database - finde the table that uses the column ie this way :

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'field_published_value'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourdb'
```

i tried on a "default install" and didnt see it :)

Comment: I found it is something to do with Message module, after I disabled Message, it works now. http://drupal.org/node/1807532

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using resource which has name "entity_user" (mabe it's nesessary activate module "eck").

I use this uri: http://mysyte/myendpoint/entity_user
I use POST method
I use same json parameters as you.

It Works for me.